# How to return false when a punctuation is present in an input

Tags: python

```py
# no periods, spaces or puctuation marks
punctuation_not_wanted = [".","!", " " "/"]

for punctuation_not_wanted in s:
    if punctuation_not_wanted in s:
       return false
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you have posted here. It looks like python code, but it contains a `return` without there being a function to return from.

Comment: you put inside a function and the first letter is upper case in `False`

Comment: what about your implementation (besides the syntax errors others mentioned) doesn't work for you? are you just running into errors? if so, please post the traceback. if not, please fully describe why this doesn't do what you're hoping

Comment: `" " "/"` Having two strings without anything between them is implicitly concatenating them. Is that intentional? The result is that it becomes `" /"`.

Comment: It is part of a larger function where punctuation marks should not be allowed from the input 's' including space

Answer (score 1):

You can compare them as sets. If they have same symbols, their intersection (`&`) will have this same symbols and will converts to True for if statement.

```py
if set(punctuation_not_wanted) & set(s):
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all([(c not in s) for c in punctuation_not_wanted])
```